# Есть ошибка или нет

Tags: пунктуация

> Да чуваки, это розыгрыш бесплатного портрета
>
> Всё что нужно для участия:
>   - подписаться на нашу страницу
>   - сделать репост этой записи
>
> Победителя определим 20 февраля случайным образом. Удачи!

Нужно ли ставить запятую после "всё" и какие еще ошибки вы можете заметить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Чувак — жаргонный (арготически окрашенный), как гласят словари, синоним слова «парень». Даже если в этом обращении учитывается только мужское население до двадцати, оставлять такое слово не следовало бы по этическим соображениям.

Розыгрыш чего-либо, за что надо платить, — лохотрон. Желательно переформулировать во избежание таких аналогий. Например: розыгрыш «Портрет в подарок».

«Определим случайным образом победителя» — лохотрон в квадрате. Из примеров лучший, что приходит в голову: Победителя определит жребий.

Запятая, а также точки после предложений, нужны.

Answer (score 1):

"Чуваков" нужно выделить запятыми с обеих сторон, поскольку это обращение. После "всё" запятая нужна, да. В конце первого предложения нужна точка (хотя можно и восклицательный знак поставить в случае соответствующей итнонации). Изначально у Вас между "удачи" и "!" был пробел, я его убрал, п. ч. перед такими знаками препинания, как *точка, запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие, вопросительный и восклицательный знаки,* пробел никогда не ставят.